# Finding point, which distances sum to all other points on the line is the lowest

Tags: algorithm, recursion, line

I've been wondering if it's possible to solve this problem in recursive or "divide and conquer" way.
Here is visualisation of my problem:

[image]

```
Input:
22 // point no 1
35 // point no 2
5  // ...
44
45
20
46

Output: 2 // point with number 2 has got the lowest sum (87)
```

I know how to do this in an iterative way, but I'm thinking about something more optimal.

Comment: Shouldn't this be migrated to computer science, as this isn't directly related to programming.

Comment: @SteveJessop computer science is about algorithms and programming is about implementing them, so in that way of thinking computer science is more general and hence better suited for this question.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker: that may be so if you were building a taxonomy from scratch, but current practice seems to me to be that questions about algorithms are on topic for SO. If a dictat from on high changes that, so be it. There is cs.stackexchange in Beta, currently the FAQ says that it's for "students, practitioners and researchers in computer science". Unless the goal is to send people in circles around the SE network, I don't think it makes sense to say that as soon as a programmer wants a non-stupid algorithm for their problem then they're practicing computer science, *not* programming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called the [median](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) value. Just sort the values and select the center. If n is even, any of the two center values will do.

There are also [O(n) algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) for calculating the median.

Comment: No, 100 has a cumulative difference of 114, the median 102 has 110.

Comment: "If n is even, any of the two center values will do" - or any point in the line segment between them, if you're allowed to choose a point on the line that *isn't* one of the points in the specified set.

Comment: Have deleted my answer stating the the point closest to the average is possibly the solution. I did some tests with lots of random sets and, with data set {2030, 2633, 4784, 5694, 5822, 5876, 6549}, the average is 4769.71, closest to 4784. However the cumul-dist for that is 9710 while the cumul-dist for the median 5694 is an annoyingly better 8800. So this is probably correct.

Comment: The outline proof is that if there are N points to the left of you, and >=N+2 points to the right of you, then where you are is not the solution to the problem, because by moving one point to the right you decrease your distance to >=N+2 points by some constant d and you increase your distance to N+1 points by the same constant d (N+1 being the N points on the left, plus the one you were at). This reduces the total. So unless you have (a) N points either side, or (b) N points on one side and N+1 the other, then you're not at the solution. Hence the solution is the median.

Comment: @SteveJessop Or that in a few sentences rather than half an essay, nice!

Answer (score 2):

The answer saying the solution is the [median](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) is correct, however there can be

### Multiple solutions

If there is an even amount of points: *p<sub>1</sub> < … p<sub>n</sub> < p<sub>n + 1</sub> < … < p<sub>2n</sub>*, the sum of distances will be minimal for any point *x*, where *p<sub>n</sub> ≤ x ≤ p<sub>n + 1</sub>

To understand why the median works, consider this

### Explanation

Let's say we have `n` points where *p<sub>i</sub> < p<sub>i+1</sub>* for all applicable `i`.

Being naive, we might think that *x = p<sub>1</sub>* is the best choice to minimize the sum *S*. Increasing *x* by one, what happens to the sum *S*? We are 1 further away from *p<sub>1</sub>*, but 1 closer to all other points.

Thus, *S<sub>p<sub>1</sub> + 1</sub> = S<sub>p<sub>1</sub></sub> + 1 - (n - 1)*

The sum continues to change in this fashion until *x = p<sub>2</sub>*: The slope is *1 - (n - 1) = 2 - n*
After having passed point *p<sub>2</sub>*, the slope changes to *2 - (n - 2) = 4 - n*, after that *6 - n*, then *8 - n* etc

It is easy to see, that the slope always increases by 2 on each point we pass: The amount of approaching points decreases by one, the amount of points that are moving away increases by one, it follows that the slope changes by 2.

At some point, the slope will change from negative to

- positive – in the case of an odd number of points
- zero – in the case of an even number of points

It is easy to see, that the slope will be zero at some point when there is an even amount of points:
*p<sub>1</sub> < p<sub>2</sub> < … p<sub>n</sub> < p<sub>n + 1</sub> < … 
p<sub>2n - 1</sub> < p<sub>2n</sub>*

If we are located between points *p<sub>n</sub>* and *p<sub>n+1</sub>*, there is an equal amount of points towards both left and right side. That means, that as we move between those two points, an equal amount of points – *n*, to be exact – comes closer and draws further away, thus the sum *S<sub>p<sub>n</sub> <= x <= p<sub>n + 1</sub></sub>* remains unchanged.

If there is an odd number of points, *p<sub>(n + 1)/2</sub>* marks the minimum, because it is the point where the slope changes from negative to positive.